# NetStream Loading ID3 information from stream in FMS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server, id3

I've been following the basic FMS instructions to load an mp3 and play it. This is working very well. I've also got a second NetStream instance (id3Stream) that should load the ID3 data from the same mp3, but all I get is a StreamNotFound error. Why would the mp3 stream and play but the id3 data be "not found"? Any help would be appreciated.

```
var url:String = "name_of_mp3";
// -- yay, I'm listening to the song
stream.play("mp3:" + url, position);
// -- boo, it's not found even though it's the same url
id3Stream.play("id3:" + url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure its your case, but I've heard that some versions of FMS have a bug with ID3v2. Apparently FMS 3.5.2 fixes this... from the [3.5.2 release notes](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flashmediaserver/releasenotes.html):

> 2285061 MP3 files with ID3v2 tags
>   failed to play.

Comment: Interesting. I'll test it out. My files are playing fine though, just the id3: prefix doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yeah, what I've heard is that play("mp3:url") works fine, while play("id3:url") returns a "Stream Not Found".